# How to create a weighted mean SpatRaster out of multiple SpatRasters in R terra

Tags: r, geospatial, raster, terra, weighted-average

I would like to create a raster, which represents the weighted mean of a number of SpatRasters per cell, i.e., I want a new raster where for every cell at position [x,y], this cell will have the weighted mean of the input SpatRasters' cells at positions [x,y].

The weights should be applied per whole raster, e.g., if raster_1 has weight 4, raster_2 2 and raster_3 1,
then for every cell of the resulting raster:
weighted_mean_raster[x,y] = (raster_1[x,y] * 4 + raster_1[x,y] * 2 + raster_1[x,y] * 1) / (4 + 2 + 1)

I am aware of the app function, and I have used it before to create a non-weighted mean raster:

```
# new raster with the mean of each cell value of the 3 other rasters
mean_raster = app(raster_1, raster_2, raster_3, fun=mean)
```

However, I cannot get this approach to work when `fun=terra::weighted.mean` whichever inputs I try to put into "weighted.mean"

Thank you very much in advance for all your help!

Comment: have your tried `rasters_wm <- terra::weighted.mean(x=c(raster_1, raster_2, raster_3), w = c(4,2,1)` ? And useful to share what approaches you tried that didn't give desired results or resulted in error.

Comment: @Chris I think this returns the required result, however, I do not understand exactly how it works; I thought that `terra::weighted.mean` only accepts one raster max. as input, and that `app` is the only way to apply functions to more than one raster simultaneously..

Comment: I interpreted `?terra::weighted.mean` `w` as a vector of weights on layers to allow applying in a `stack` of layers and terra stacks with `c(...)`. It is likely that this only fortuitously worked in this instance as rasters 1:3 each only had 1 layer so the `w` parameter was properly allocated. With more layers per raster, perhaps something like `w = c(3:4, 7:9, 10)` with rast1=2 layers, rast2=3 layers, rast3= 1 layer.  I guess one could make some small experimental rasters to check using 0:1 values. AND, I could be wrong and `app(` is the way to go.

Comment: rast1 = rast(array(sample(0:1, 32, replace = TRUE), dim = c(4,4,2)))
rast2 = rast(array(sample(0:1, 48, replace = TRUE), dim = c(4,4,3)))
rast3 = rast(array(sample(0:1, 16, replace = TRUE), dim = c(4,4,1)))
> rast_all_wm2 = terra::weighted.mean(c(rast1, rast2, rast3), w = c(1:2, 3:1, 1))
doesn't error, returns a single layer, but it more complicated than I can just say, wow. In this notation `w` is referring to increased weight being rast1 layer1>layer2, rast2 layer3>layer2>layer1. Still not simplified enough an example to say yes, that was exactly right. One who knows more will come along

Comment: `weighted.mean(` and `app(` examples to weighted mean when implemented in `terra` [issues 189](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/189) and [updated code](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/commit/f0384f650d228e31068bef48e6445df22592d37b) that are useful for their error messages as we ask ourselves, 'Am I doing this right, is it calculating right?', and I get from these I was `doing things wrong` with my `c(...` approach to `w` weights and likely as to layers as well.